# Windows Server 2008 small business server 64-Bit Vmware Server 2 IIS 7 HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

Tags: windows, iis, vmware-server

I've tried to install vmware server 2 on a small business server 2008 host and IIS 7 stopped working. Everytime I tried to access any website on the server including OWA I get HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable. I've tried to restart the IIS services and websites with no luck. Removed vmware server and the problem persists. There are no errors in the application logs concerning IIS or anything related. I'm stumped. Does anyone have an idea what's happenning here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That's because VMware Server 2 installs a Web Server (Tomcat IIRC) on the host which is used for management that is conflicting with IIS.

VMware's [Release notes for Server 2.0](http://www.vmware.com/support/server2/doc/releasenotes_vmserver2.html) states:

> If you want to use ports 80 (HTTP) and
>   443 (HTTPS), override the default
>   values during installation.
>
> Note:
>   If you are running IIS or Apache web
>   server on the default ports, specify
>   alternate HTTP and HTTP ports when
>   prompted by the Windows installer or
>   vmware-config.pl